# How to make paddings unclickable

Tags: html, css

Here is the code, when I put this in the code `padding: 0 0 0 400px;` the entire field including the padding is being clicked:

```css
.navbar ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar li {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 400px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Bookman Old Style;
  color: #99ED09;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="link1.html" target="Here">Anime</a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="link2.html" target="Here">Movies</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use margins instead of padding.

Comment: paddings and borders are part of the element itself as @NinoŠkopac points use margins instead .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've replaced your **padding: 0 0 0 400px;** with **margin: 0 0 0 400px;**.

```css
.navbar ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navbar li {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 400px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Bookman Old Style;
  color: #99ED09;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="link1.html" target="Here">Anime</a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="link2.html" target="Here">Movies</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **margins** instead of padding.

```
.navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 400px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Bookman Old Style;
  color: #99ED09;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the parent(ul) to position: relative and then position: absolute on the child(li) elements

```
.navbar ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar li{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Bookman Old Style;
    color: #99ED09;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your site will not be responsive then just replace 'padding: 0 0 0 400px;' with 'margin: 0 0 0 400px;'